# Verify a postgresql index can be dropped securely

Tags: performance, index, postgresql-12

Indexes use resources because they have to be updated when data changes.
How to check if an index can be securely dropped (ie. not used at all)?

This request seems to return the unused indexes, assuming the database did not restart and index stats were not reset for a decent period:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_stat_all_indexes
WHERE schemaname <> 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname <> 'pg_toast'
     AND idx_scan = 0
     AND idx_tup_read = 0
     AND idx_tup_fetch = 0
```

Is this request exhaustive to verify an index is droppable without reducing database performance?

On another hand, is it possible to measure an index maintenance cost?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but you should verify that the metrics you mention are not reset during the restart of postgres.

Comment: Thank you, checked with "SELECT min(backend_start) AS last_restart_time
FROM pg_stat_activity;"

Comment: I meant, just make sure that the metrics are preserved during restart. Otherwise, you may get a false positive for "index not used" due to that postgres was restarted after your critical index was last used. Perhaps, that is what you meant with your query above, just wanted to clarify my intention